# Keras LocallyConnected1D layer

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I have a very specific problem that I am trying to solve. It seems very straightforward, but I am not able to implement that in keras. For example I have a an input_dim = 300. On which I have to apply a filter of size 100 with stride 100. So basically use each of the 100 columns of the vector independently and then apply an activation on each of them. So then I have 3 outputs which would then be connected to a fully connected layer, which I know how to do. I tried googling and referring the Keras documentation, but it is very unclear as to what would be the values of the parameters should be. I apologize if the question is a bit vague. 
[image: it looks something like this]

I would also like to add that this is one way that I could think of to get the configuration I mentioned in the figure. Something like 3 perceptrons connected to form a layer and then connected to another dense layer. But there could be other ways.

Comment: So what have you tried? Won't it just be `LocallyConnected1D(3, 100, input_shape=(None, 300))`?

Comment: I am new to Keras and I had a hard time understanding what the arguments meant. Moreover the above doesn't work :(. I ll edit the question and add a diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, I had got the shape of the output all wrong. Once you are that the filter is of size 100 and the stride is of size 100, it is obvious and it is also obvious to keras that the output activation layer is of size 3. The first parameter on the other hand possibly (I haven't tried this) deals with depth of the filter if each input neuron itself is multidimensional. Something like RGB values. Now why it is still called 1D, well that I am not sure. Possibly because the arrangement of the neurons is still 1D. But here is how you do it.

```
model.add(LocallyConnected1D(1, 100, strides=100, input_shape=(300, 1)))
```

Comment: It is called 1D because it is only "moved" in one dimension, along the "time". A 2D should also be moved in another dimension.